# How to count frequency of elements from a columns of lists in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: list, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, frequency-analysis

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like the following,

```
data2 = [("James",["A x","B z","C q","D", "E"]),
    ("Michael",["A x","C","E","K", "D"]),
    ("Robert",["A y","R","B z","B","D"]),
    ("Maria",["X","A y","B z","F","B"]),
    ("Jen",["A","B","C q","F","R"])
  ]

 
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["Name", "My_list" ])

df2
    Name    My_list
0   James   [A x, B z, C q, D, E]
1   Michael     [A x, C, E, K, D]
2   Robert  [A y, R, B z, B, D]
3   Maria   [X, A y, B z, F, B]
4   Jen     [A, B, C q, F, R]
```

I want to be able to count the elements in the column 'My_list' and sort in descending order? For example,

```
'A x' appeared -> P times, 
'B z' appeared -> Q times, and so on.
```

Can someone please put some lights on this? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command explodes the array, and provides the count of each element

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_ans = (df2
           .withColumn("explode", F.explode("My_list"))
           .groupBy("explode")
           .count()
           .orderBy(F.desc("count"))
```

the result is

[image]